# VS 2012 - Breakpoint Window hangs and freezes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, freeze

When I open the breakpoint window in Visual Studio 2012, I start to see a lot of hang time - we're talking 30+ seconds to load the entire thing, 6+ seconds between clicking a single break point and seeing it become selected.

The biggest problem is I cannot delete break points, not even one at a time - VS just goes completely unresponsive.  I've gone as far as giving it 10 minutes to think about it, but that didn't work.

I suspect the problem is I have too many breakpoints left over from previous sessions - but like I said, I can't delete them.  Is there another way to delete those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out - deleting the .suo file for the affected solution(s) will clear all break points, as well as other solution-specific options (such as what files you had open).  Use this as an alternative if you can't select and delete any or all breakpoints from the Breakpoint window.

Answer (score 1):

Debug Menu -> Delete All Breakpoints does the job.

Comment: In my case, this wasn't working either, hence the need for a SO post.  Something behind the scenes was throwing an exception, causing 'Delete All' to fail - I can only guess as to what, maybe a code merge over an already messy environment caused something to misbehave.  9 times out of 10, this would be the obvious answer, but when even that fails, nuking the .suo file seems to be the only option left.